# How to update a table with a foreach without overwriting?

Tags: php, sql, foreach, sql-update, overwrite

So i'm working on a university project but i have a problem that's really starting to bother me.
I am trying to update my database several times with different values, except that only the last value will be taken into account : they're overwriting themselves.

My code :

```php
$id_structure = $_POST['id_structure'];
```

```
foreach ($id_structure as $id2) {
      $id_structure = explode(",", $id2);
      updateDemandeStructure($id_demande[0], $id2, 0);
}
```

And my SQL method is like this :

```
function updateDemandeStructure($id_demande, $id_structure, $principale) {
    global $bd;
    $stmt = $bd->prepare('UPDATE demandes_structures SET id_structure = :id_structure, principale = :principale WHERE id_demande = :id_demande');
    $stmt->bindParam(ID_DEMANDE, $id_demande);
    $stmt->bindParam(ID_STRUCTURE, $id_structure);
    $stmt->bindParam(':principale', $principale);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

So for example if I (id_demande = 1) choose 4 new structures with their id_structure : 22,23,24,25, I'm going to have my table who looks like :

| ID_DEMANDE | ID_STRUCTURE | PRINCIPALE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 0 |
| 1 | 25 | 0 |
| 1 | 25 | 0 |
| 1 | 25 | 0 |

Please does anyone know what to modify in my code so that my table looks like this after my update?

| ID_DEMANDE | ID_STRUCTURE | PRINCIPALE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 0 |
| 1 | 23 | 0 |
| 1 | 24 | 0 |
| 1 | 25 | 0 |

Thank you very much!

Comment: an `UPDATE` updates all eligible rows which match the criteria. It does not always update one row at a time. Therefore, each time you run the UPDATE, it will indeed overwrite the values in all rows which match the ID_DEMANDE value. If you want to put a different value in each row, you need some way of distinguishing between the rows so you can uniquely identify the specific row you want to change each time. From what you've posted so far, it's unclear to us how you might go about that, so it's hard to suggest anything meaningful. Does the table have any other columns?

Comment: Or maybe if there's no other information you can use to help you, the alternative is simply to `DELETE` all rows which match the `ID_DEMANDE` and then `INSERT` new ones with the desired structure, because then you can control precisely what goes into each new row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and no this table (demande_structures) has only 3 columns (id_demande, id_structure and principale).

Comment: Ok well then I think you would just have to delete the existing rows and re-create them with the new values.

Comment: @ADyson is wrong,  in mysql and as far as i know every databse updates row by row, you you ca use a user define variable to update the number, which database are you using?

Comment: But as your columns have no unique column you will get a problme

Comment: @nbk you're right in the sense that an UPDATE can be row by row, but only if there's actually something to uniquely identify each target row. I already said that in my comments, so I don't believe I'm incorrect, unless you can clarify your point further? In this case, as you have also noticed, there is nothing to uniquely identify them, hence the issue.

Comment: @nbk Yes, my table has no unique variable, because its a join table : id_demande is the foreign key of demande and id_structure is the foreign key of structure. Does that mean I need to add a column with a unique id ? Or to do like ADyson said ?

Comment: first add the database you are using , my dynamic approach can work and will be dynamic , but Adysqon approach is faster

Comment: Why not simply modify the table and add a column that would make this possible. Even a sequential number for each set would do, in which case you could target e.g. `id_demande = 1 AND seq_num = 2` that, in combination, would be unique. In other possibilities, the `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ` syntax won't let you target the Nth member of each set (e.g.. `LIMIT 2,1`) in MySQL, as LIMIT in UPDATE only holds a row count condition. What @ADyson said, keep it simple and just delete and reinsert, if you don't want to modify your table (why not?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your answers, as I'm running out of time, I decided to choose @ADyson's solution :

Instead of doing like this :

```
foreach ($id_structure as $id2) {
      $id_structure = explode(",", $id2);
      updateDemandeStructure($id_demande[0], $id2, 0);
}
```

I did this :

```
deleteDemandeStructure($id_demande[0]);

foreach ($id_structure as $id2) {
      $id_structure = explode(",", $id2);
      addDemandeStructure($id_demande[0], $id2, 0);
}
```

I'll come back to you if I have time to set up a more dynamic version!